# passing variable value php

Tags: php, variables

there is 2 pages , one is the main and the other included to it

the main page

```
<?php
$var_value = 7;
$_SESSION['varname'] = $var_value;
include 'upload_image.php';
?>
```

and the included page

```
<?php
include 'init.php';

if (!logged_in()) {
header('Location: index.php');
exit();
} 

include 'template/header.php';  
?>

<h3>Upload image</h3>

<?php

if (isset($_FILES['image'], $_POST['image_n'], $_POST['image_description'])) {
$image_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
$bytes = $_FILES['image']['size'];
$image_temp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
$image_n = $_POST['image_n'];
$image_description = $_POST['image_description'];

$allowed_ext = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif', 'rar', 'pdf');
//$image_ext = strtolower(end(explode('.', $image_name)));

$image_ext = pathinfo($image_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

$album_id = $_SESSION['varname'];

$errors = array();

if (empty($image_name) || empty($album_id) || empty($image_n) ||         empty($image_description)) {

    $errors[] = 'Something is missing';
} else {

if (strlen($album_name) > 55 || strlen($album_description) > 255) {
        $errors[] = 'One or more fields contains too many characters';
    }

if (in_array($image_ext, $allowed_ext) === false) {
    $errors[] = 'File type not allowed';

}

//if ($image_size > 2097152) {
//  $errors[] = 'Maximum file size is 2mb';
//}

if (album_check($album_id) === false) {
    $errors[] = 'Couldn\'t upload to that album';
}

}

if (!empty($errors)) {
    foreach ($errors as $error) {
        echo $error, '<br />';
    }

} else {
    $byte = formatSizeUnits($bytes);
    upload_image($image_temp, $image_ext, $album_id, $image_n, $image_description, $byte);
    header('Location: view_album.php?album_id='.$album_id);
    exit();
}
}

$albums = get_albums();

if (empty($albums)) {
echo'<p>You don\'t have any albums. <a href="create_album.php">Create an album</a></p>';
} else {
?>

<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="choose">
    <p>Choose a file:<br /><input type="file" name="image" /></p>
    </div>
        <div class="des">
        <p>Name*:<br /><input type="text" name="image_n" maxlength="55"/></p>
        <p>Description*:<br /><textarea name="image_description" rows="6" cols="35" maxlength="255"></textarea></p>


    <p><input type="submit" value="Upload" /></p>
    </div>
</form>
<div class="foot">
<?php   
}

include 'template/footer.php';  
?>
</div>
```

the form at the end of the second page does not load .. but when i delete the first line at the main page $var_value = 7 ; the form at the end load .. i don't know what is the problem or there is other way to set the album value in the main and pass it to the included page

Comment: missing `session_start()`

Comment: @Dagon Nah... the OP just didn't post it. They never do (remember). ...ah, but then again.

Comment: What is the value of `$var_value` if you don't re-assign it? The included file uses `$_SESSION['varname']` as the album ID to look up, so you're changing the ID.

Comment: @Fred-ii- assume nothing! :-)

Comment: Don't I know it. As the expression goes... you know, about "assume"? Knew it. 99.5% of the time, the OP comes out and says "yeah I have it... blah blah"... Could this be part of the remainding .5%?!

Comment: Boy I tell ya... the word of the day is definitely "ASSUME".

Comment: please check the functionality of album_check($album_id)
also set ini_set('display_errors',1); in main 1st line

Comment: @Neo function album_check($album_id) {
 $album_id = (int)$album_id;
 $query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`album_id`) FROM `albums` WHERE `album_id`=$album_id AND `user_id`=".$_SESSION['user_id']);
 return (mysql_result($query, 0) == 1) ? true : false;
}

Comment: please execute your code with set ini_set('display_errors',1); in main as 1st line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are no problems found in `$album_id`, which is set from `$var_value`, the included file does:

```
$byte = formatSizeUnits($bytes);
upload_image($image_temp, $image_ext, $album_id, $image_n, $image_description, $byte);
header('Location: view_album.php?album_id='.$album_id);
exit();
```

So it never gets to the part that displays the form.

Comment: when i delete var_value = 7; the form load !!

Comment: It only exits if there are no problems with `$album_id`. If you don't set `$var_value`, then `$album_id` will be undefined, and that's a problem. So it displays an error and then displays the form.

Comment: so why it doesn't load when i put $var_value = 7; ?

Comment: Because then the checks on `$album_id` are successful, and it goes to the code I quoted instead of displaying the form.

Answer (score 0):

The second code is included? If so than you can just use

```
$album_id = $var_value
```

Instead of:

```
$album_id = $_SESSION['varname'];
```

in the second peace of code... No need for an session.

Comment: I suspect the included file is intended to be used from multiple callers, so it can't assume a particular variable in the caller.